# How many times can quadric kiss cosine at given point?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, contest-math, conic-sections

Let a quadric $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ touches the plot of $y=\cos(x)$ at the point $(0,1)$ with multiplicity $n$. What is the maximum possible value of $n$? Recall that a joint point $P$ of parametrized curves $r_1(t)$ and $r_2(t)$ is said to be a tangent point of multiplicity $n$ if the first $n$ derivatives of $r_1(t)$ and  $r_2(t)$ at the point $P$ are equal.

PS. That was asked as one of the problems of a student mathematical olimpiad in Russia. The author gives general directions and the answer $n=5$.

Comment: Your definition of multiplicity is fishy: Consider $r_1(t):=t$, $\>r_2(t):=t-t^2$. – Said multiplicity should deal with geometrical objects and not with parametric representations.

Comment: That's all right as $r(t):=(x(t),y(t)).$ In your one-dimensional example zero is a tangent point of multiplicity one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry the quadric we are looking for has an apex at $(0,1)$, whereby a parabola $y=1- p x^2$ obviously won't do. Therefore the equation of this quadric will be of the form 
$a x^2+ c y^2 +e y + f=0$ with $c\ne0$. Solving for $y$ and taking care of $y(0)=1$ we obtain an expression of the form
$$y(x)=1\pm\bigl(\sqrt{q^2 + r x^2} -q\bigr)$$
with $q\geq0$ and $r$ to be determined such that $$y^{(k)}(0)=\cos^{(k)}(0)\qquad(0\leq k\leq n)\tag{1}$$ and $n$ as large as possible. Doing the computation one finds that the hyperbolic arc
$$y(x)=4-\sqrt{9+3x^2}$$
and no other quadric satisfies $(1)$ with $n=5$. Since  for this arc one has
$$y(x)=1-{x^2\over2}+{x^4\over24}-{x^6\over144}+\ {\rm higher\ terms}$$
it follows that $(1)$ cannot be satisfied with $n=6$. Therefore $n=5$ is indeed the maximal order of kissing between a quadric and the cosine curve at $(0,1)$.

Comment: Here we know the power series, so the process can be reversed to go from the series to the conic without fitting the coefficients.  (See "More edit" addendum to other answer.)

Answer (score 0):

There are $4$ free parameters when passing a conic through a given point, so fourth-order contact for a general smooth function at a general point, but it is possible to have higher order contact at special points of a general curve, or at many points of a special curve (such as an arc of a conic).

[Edit: this corrects the value of $3$ given earlier.  Increase all values in the comments by $1$ for the order of tangency.

There is a symmetry of the graph of $y=\cos x$ relative to the line $x=0$, so that the local approximating conic should have enhanced contact by order at least $1$, or order $\geq 5$ tangency.  There is no reason to suppose an additional accident occurs, so order $= 5$ stated in the revised question is perfectly sensible and would say that the quality of approximation is the same as for any generic smooth even function at $x=0$.  A computation is needed to check this by finding the approximating conic and verifying that there is no extra tangency more than predicted.]

[More edit: in the power series for $y = \cos x$ we can, up to $O(x^6)$ error, replace the $\frac{x^4}{24}$ by $\frac{(1-y)^2}{6}$ and this gives order $\geq 5$ tangency to a conic: $y = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{(1-y)^2}{6} + O(x^6)$. A computation of the $x^6$ term is needed to show that $\geq 6$ does not happen. As written earlier, there is nothing unique to $\cos x$ here, and a generic even power series would have the same order of tangency at $0$.]

Comment: I find it rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: Or it is a clue about several things.  One is that (as the answer implies) there is no general rule, so to solve the problem one has no choice but to perform specific fitting of parameters to the curve.  Another is a constraint: if your answer is less than $3$, it is probably wrong.  A final one is that answers are posted for many reasons, not all of which involve strangers giving you complete personal satisfaction within minutes.  If it helps you save time in solving the problem, great.  If you already knew it, somebody else might not.  If you did not, the customary reply involves gratitude.

Comment: Many thanks from me to you for the attention to my question and your hint. I wiil be waiting for a constructive answer.

Comment: As underlined in my comment, it is probably unmistakably clear by now to most people reading that you have already received a constructive answer.  And your continued comments are doing a good job of reducing the probability that any new answers might appear.  Good luck with your calculations, because there is nothing more that answers of any kind can offer you here except doing the computation for you completely.  There are a few derivatives to be matched, and that is that.  If you are asking people to calculate it for you, just announce that.

Comment: Could you indicate the maximum value of $n$?

Comment: You will need to successively find linear conditions on the coefficients of the conic to ensure $n$ is at least $0$, then $1$, then $2$, etc until the process stops, and this is done by matching derivatives of order 0,1,2,... on the two curves.  It is a tedious computation and nothing more to it than that.

Comment: By the way, the reason why "you will need to" calculate is that probably nobody reading this, including me, has any idea what the maximum $n$ is except that it is at least $3$ for the general reasons outlined in the answer.  It is not possible to magically see what the maximum $n$ is, any more than to know the precise location of a solution to a polynomial by reading the equation.  There is only a computational procedure to eventually determine the answer.  It could be that the answer is $\geq 4$ due to symmetry at the maximum of $\cos x$, but it is hard to be certain without a calculation.

Comment: See latest edit.